# Jackson JsonCreator not working in Enum

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum Option {
    ADDRESS("address"),
    TELEPHONE("telephone");

    private String value;

    Option(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Option forValue(@JsonProperty("value") String value) {
        for (Option o: Option.values()) {
            if (o.value.equals(value)) {
                return o;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Given the JSON input:

```
{
    "value":"address"
}
```

I would expect to get back an ADDRESS enum, but this is not working, instead if i do a:

```
@JsonCreator
public static Option forValue(@JsonProperty("value") String value) {
    System.out.println(value);
    ...
}
```

I get back a single bracket "{" character only (printed to the console).
What is wrong?

EDIT:

I do that using JAX-RS and Resteasy on Wildfly

```
@Path("/plans")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PlanRESTService {    

    @POST
    @Path("/{id:\\d+}/options")
    public Response createPlanOption(@PathParam("id") Long id, Option option) {
        ...
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

Registered Jackson provider:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonContextResolver() {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to deserialize?

Comment: You just complicated everything with JAX-RS. What you should do is put a breakpoint inside the `forValue` and check what is calling it. Is it Jackson (unlikely) or whatever JAX-RS uses for converting with methods called `forValue`.

Comment: This is now less about jackson and more about JAX-RS by the way.

Comment: I've registered the Jackson provider for JAX-RS, evrything else in the project is serialized/deserialized using Jackson and it is working as expected!